# Merge [luggage] into [cargo]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The [cargo](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cargo) use case says:

> Carrying stuff with your bike, using racks, backpacks, trailers, etc.

All the luggage questions are about carrying things on the bike except these two about

- [Packing a bicycle in a suitcase](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/71962/33084)
- [Airline baggage costs](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/51562/33084)

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree with this.  Cargo is about carrying bulky/heavy stuff in a very general way and can include different types of trailers, and bakfiets or other specialized bicycles.  Luggage is a category of tools that *can* be used to load cargo onto your bike, but I (and the people I normally discuss riding, especially commuting, with) wouldn't normally consider a change of clothes, a laptop, or a bottle of fancy olives and some cheese from a shop as "cargo."  A messenger bag would be "luggage" but it wouldn't be practical for carrying "cargo."  A question about the best luggage to carry and protect a laptop doesn't feel like a good fit for the tag "cargo."

Comment: I feel like your beef is then with the [cargo] usage instructions.